# How to calculate the integral $\int\limits_{-10}^{10}\frac{3^x}{3^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I have to calculate this integral:
$$\int\limits_{-10}^{10}\frac{3^x}{3^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}dx$$

I know that this function ie. $$3^{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}$$ is periodic with period $T=1$ so I rewrote the integral as $$20\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3^x}{3^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}dx$$

But the problem is that I can't figure out how to calculate the final integral.

Comment: @PeterForeman I just figured it out myself. It was really stupid of me to not see it but thanks anyway.

Comment: @DonAntonio the fractional part function {$x$} is periodic so this one is automatically periodic right?

Comment: @DonAntonio this is what makes it periodic. The function is $3^{\{ x\}}$ where $\{ x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$ which is obviously the same as $\{ x+1\}$ so we have $\forall x\in[-10,10]: f(x)=f(x+1)$.

Comment: @infinite-blank- Of course. you're right. Thanks, deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x-[x]=\{x\}$ is fractional part which is periodic with period 1. Your integral covers 20 cycles of period 1 So
$$I=\int_{-10}^{10} 3^{\{x\}} dx =20 \int_{0}^{1} 3^x dx=20 \frac{3^1-1}{\ln3}= \frac{40}{\ln 3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\int_{-10}^{10} \frac{3^x}{3^{\lfloor x\rfloor }}\,\mathrm d x=\sum_{i=-9}^{10}\frac{1}{3^{k-1}}\int_{k-1}^k 3^x\,\mathrm d x.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-10}^{10}\frac{3^x}{3^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}dx=20\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3^x}{3^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}dx=20\int_{0}^{1}{3^x}dx=20\left[\frac{3^x}{\ln3}\right]^1_0=\frac{40}{\ln3}$$
For first step to second step, we note that $3^{\lfloor x\rfloor}=1$ for $0\le x<1$ as $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$.

Comment: Actually  $\lfloor x\rfloor=0, 3^{\lfloor x\rfloor}=1$  for $0\le x<1$

Answer (score 1):

$$20 \int\limits_{x=0}^1 3^x\ dx = \frac{40}{\ln 3}$$ (as given by Dr Azfar Ahmed)

[image]